# Pattern for generic communication framework (handling and exposing received data)

Tags: c#, xml, sockets, generics, types

I am currently a good portion of the way through developing a socket based implementation of a generic communication "framework" that works between C# and Android.

Building the server and client has been easy enough. Nothing too technically challenging about that.

At this point the implementation contains 2 major components.

> AndroidTcpListener (tcp socket class
>   that handles communication) 
>   AndroidTcpServer (class that creates
>   an instance of the TcpListener and
>   handles the DataReceived (from the
>   TcpListener) when data is received)
>
> Data is sent between the client and
>   the server using the standard XML
>   serializer (I may move to JSON at some
>   point but for the time being I have
>   settled on XML)

Where I seem to be completely stuck is how to handle and expose the data received.

I have tried using generics but no matter how I structure it, it seems that in the end I end up having to create an `AndroidTcpServer<T>` which then restricts me to a single datatype.

I have tried creating a CustomActivator class as such

```
class CustomActivator<T> where T : Serialization.ITcpSerializable<T>
{
    public CustomActivator(String xmlTypeName, Byte[] data) 
    {
        this.XmlTypeName = xmlTypeName;
        this.Data = data;
    }

    public String XmlTypeName { get; set; }
    public Byte[] Data { get; set; }

    public T Activate()
    {
        T res =  Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(this.Data))
        {
            return res.Deserialize(XElement.Load(stream));               
        }
    }
}
```

But again this seems to restrict me to implementing `AndroidTcpServer<T>`

I have tried creating an AndroidTcpEvent class which is structured as such

```
public class AndroidTcpEvent<T>
{
    public AndroidTcpEvent() { }
    public AndroidTcpEvent(String eventName, T data)
    {
        this.EventName = eventName;
        this.Data = data;
    }

    public String EventName { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

But the XMLSerializer seems to refuse to want to serialize it (I guess I could implement my own serializer but this is far from trivial and doesnt really solve how I will expose the data)

I have tried countless other approaches which all seem to hit a dead end somewhere.

So basically at this point I have (Inside of the AndroidTcpServer class a method as such

```
private void DataReceived(Object sender, TcpServerMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Data = Byte[] of XML serialized data of the message sent (Semantics are unimportant)
}
```

In conclusion I am hoping for some guidance on how one would typically handle exposing data received and actually creating instances of the data in such a  generic framework and if there are any known patterns that can be used for this problem?

Obviously I could scrape all this generic implementation stuff and just create a custom implementation for whatever app I end up trying to build but I am doing this as both a learning exercise and something that I would like to release into the public for others to use.

Hopefully I have been clear but if anyone requires clarification on any aspect of this please let me know. Thanks in advance for everyones input.

Comment: Well, how do you know which objects come across the wire? All the xml serializers I've seen require you to know the type you want to deserialize.

Comment: You know because it is expressed as part of the XML and you can use reflection to do the type matching (IE: <ArrayOfStock>). Not perfect but it works. Alternatively I am considering passing in another group of XML with each transfer that contains type information. Not sure yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think the responsibilty of the server should end with raising the `TcpServerMessageReceived` event. It's task is to listen for incoming connections and receive data and then notify anyone who is interested.

Then you can attach your custom activator to that event maybe like this:

```
class CustomActivator<T> where T : Serialization.ITcpSerializable<T>
{
    public void ListenTo(AndroidTcpServer server)
    {
         server.TcpServerMessageReceived += DataReceived;
    }

    private void DataReceived(object sender, TcpServerMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        T res =  Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(e.Data))
        {
            OnObjectReceived(res.Deserialize(XElement.Load(stream));               
        }
    }

    protected void OnObjectReceived(T obj)
    {
        var handler = ObjectReceived;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            OnObjectReceived(this, new ObjectReceivedEventArgs(obj));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about the types of objects you send across the wire. If you can determine the type which is contained in the serialized xml before you actually need to deserialize the whole object then you can modify your `CustomActivator` so that it checks the type and ignores it if it is not its own `T` (hope that makes sense) and you attach activators for each type you can receive (maybe you can use reflection to attach all types implementing the `ISerializable` interface automatically).

**Update**: If you can guess the type from the incoming data you could do something like this:

```
class GenericActivator
{
    public void ListenTo(AndroidTcpServer server)
    {
         server.TcpServerMessageReceived += DataReceived;
    }

    private void DataReceived(object sender, TcpServerMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = Type.GetType(GuessTypeName(e.Data));

        var res =  Activator.CreateInstance(t) as typeof(ITcpSerializable<>).MakeGenericType(t);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(e.Data))
        {
            OnObjectReceived(res.Deserialize(XElement.Load(stream));               
        }
    }

    protected void OnObjectReceived(object obj)
    {
        var handler = ObjectReceived;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            OnObjectReceived(this, new ObjectReceivedEventArgs(obj));
        }
    }
}
```

You could also add a type registry to `GenericActivator` where you can register listeners for each type like this:

```
class GenericActivator
{
     private Dictionary<Type, List<Action<object>> _TypeListeners;

     public void Register<T>(Action<object> objectReceived)
     {
         List<Action<object>> listeners;
         if (!_TypeListeners.TryGet(typeof(T), out listeners)
         {
             listeners = new List<Action<object>>();
         }
         listeners.Add(objectReceived);
     }
}
```

And then only call the listeners for the type received. Makes the assumption that `GuessTypeName` works reliably.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is actually along the path I have been considering (probably a bit neater actually).